# classifying matrices up to congruence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Square complex matrices can be classified up to similarity where similarity is defined like so:
$A\sim B$ if there exists invertible matrix C such that $CAC^{-1}=B$
All matrices are similar to some matrix in [jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)

Say we instead consider this definition of similarity known as [congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence):
$A\sim B$ if there exists invertible matrix C such that $CAC^T=B$
(just as it is defined in wikipedia, I make no assumptions on C other than invertiblility)
Is there a similar classification theorem for this notion of similarity?

Comment: The second definition describe the notion of congruence between matrices.

Comment: thanks for this, I have edited the question accordingly

Comment: Are you assuming that $C^T$ is the inverse of $C$ in your second scenario?

Comment: no, I am not assuming this

Comment: For symmetric matrices this corresponds to treating them as quadratic forms, see [matrix congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence). The classification is much simpler as they are all congruent to [diagonal ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Real_quadratic_forms). Over $\mathbb{R}$ they are classified by signatures, and over $\mathbb{C}$ just by ranks. In particular, all non-degenerate ones are congruent.